# C++ implementation of a C preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Does anyone know of a good C++ implementation of a standard **C** preprocessor?

I'm working on a C++ project which involves parsing **C** code, and I'd like to support macros etc but am not interested in implementing a **C** preprocessor myself.

Ideally, the preprocessor would take in the filename of the main **C** file, and would return a stream of preprocessed **C** code.

Failing this, can anyone recommend a concise but comprehensive reference which covers **C** preprocessing?

Comment: did you look for lex/yacc files for that?

Comment: Most C or C++ compilers include a command line switch that lets you output just the preprocessed file.  In the past, many code analysis tools (including several in-house tools that I wrote) used that preprocessing feature to avoid having to implement their own.  I know that Microsoft's C++ compiler had this feature 15 years ago, and I suspect it still does.  And I'm pretty sure GNU cpp does, as well.

Comment: @Ignacio: Oh god, don't get me started on the GNU cpp. It's the worst - I'm definitely not using it! Kidding, of course. I didn't I could use it for this, but it looks good so far. Maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: I'd recommend against trying to implement it yourself unless you have the time to dedicate to doing it.  Its behavior is underspecified and there are a lot of quirks, especially if you want to handle all of the features of all four preprocessors (C90, C99, C++03, and C++0x).

Comment: @James: That was exactly my thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU cpp, part of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), is very flexible and very good at parsing and preprocessing C code, although it's written in C instead of C++.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize I could use GCC for this! It being C code is fine, since I might end up just calling it externally anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look at [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/wave/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [Lex and Yacc](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/)(also known as Flex and Bison, respectively). These are tools used for parsing languages. [This excellent book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565920002) is available in any respectable university library.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: because these tools are just tools: You still need to write c/c++ code to manipulate the parse tokens/grammar results. Granted this might be overkill for a preprocessor.

Comment: They also don't really help with the hard parts of the preprocessor (namely macro replacement, which has extraordinarily convoluted rules).